# _mm256_store_epi32 was not declared

Tags: c++, gcc, intrinsics, avx, avx512

Basically, my program is like:

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
...
int* buf = (int*)_mm_malloc(sizeof(int) * 8, 32);
__m256i vi;
//some operations on vi
...
_mm256_store_epi32(buf, vi);
_mm_free(buf)
```

Compiler complained "**error: ‘_mm256_store_epi32’ was not declared in this scope...note: suggested alternative: ‘_mm256_store_epi64’**" when building the program(with flags`-mavx -mavx2`). What puzzled me was it compiled successfully once replace with `_mm256_store_epi64`. My gcc version is of 7.5.0.
a similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549630/c-intrinsic-not-declared), but it didn't help. Can anybody provide me any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

According to the intrinsics guide (https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_store_epi32&expand=5573,5567,5567,5567) the
`_mm256_store_epi32` intrinsic requires these CPUID Flags: AVX512VL + AVX512F.

May be should you use `-mavx512vl -mavx512f`to make this intrinsic available (provided your hardware target has support for it).

Comment: Hi, my flags are `-msse -msse2 -msse3 -msse4 -msse4a -mavx -mavx2 -mavx512vl -mavx512f -std=c++11
`, but it didn't work either

Comment: @Finley: probably not all compilers bother to provide the weird `_mm256_store_epi32` AVX512 intrinsic, because it has no advantage over `_mm256_store_si256` (except nicer prototype: a `void*` arg instead of `__m256i*`).  See [How to emulate \_mm256\_loadu\_epi32 with gcc or clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59649287).  Either way you want it to compile to a `vmovdqa [mem], ymm`, not a 2-byte-larger `vmovqa32 [mem], ymm`

Comment: @PeterCordes `_mm256_store_si256` worked, thanks!